# Iterate over Treeview items and get value

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, ttk

I have the following code for a ttk Treeview:

```
listbox = ttk.Treeview(
    tab_player,
    columns=('Player', 'Rating', 'Price'),
    selectmode="extended",
    show="headings"
)

listbox.heading('#1', text='Player', anchor=tk.CENTER)
listbox.heading('#2', text='Rating', anchor=tk.CENTER)
listbox.heading('#3', text='Price', anchor=tk.CENTER)
listbox.column('#1', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=80)
listbox.column('#2', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=20)
listbox.column('#3', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=30)

listbox.grid(row=5, column=5, rowspan=7, sticky=W)
```

My insert function is as follows:

```
def insertitem():
        GUI.listbox.insert('', 'end', values = (GUI.listbox_content.get(), 
                                                GUI.listboxr_content.get(), 
                                                GUI.listbox_content_price.get()))
```

Later on I want to iterate over the Treeview and get the values form each column per line, to use the values for filling in some forms on a website with selenium.

[image]

example:

```
str_libo_p = GUI.listbox.column.__getattribute__('Player')
str_libo_r = GUI.listbox.column.__getattribute__('Rating')
str_libo_price = GUI.listbox.column.__getattribute__('Price')

                #### some uninteresting code in between

                for i, r, p in zip(str_libo_p, str_libo_r, str_libo_price):
                    # values will be used to fill specific entry fields on a website.
                    # just as an example to let you know what I am using it for:
                    text_playername = init_webdriver.wait.until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                            (
                                By.XPATH,
                                (
                                    #####
                                ),
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    text_playername.click()
                    text_playername.send_keys(i)

                    # same will be done for text_player_rating.send_keys(r) and 
                    # text_player_price.send_keys(p) with different XPATHs
```

From the documentation I am not understanding which function I should call here, to get a value in return.
`GUI.listbox.column.__getattribute__('Price')` is not giving me the result I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the row_id of a `Treeview` using `.get_children()` and get the values of each row using `.item(row_id)["value"]`:

```py
for row_id in GUI.listbox.get_children():
    i, r, p = GUI.listbox.item(row_id)["values"]
    ...
    text_playername.send_keys(i)
```

Comment: thanks. But I somehow have to get the values from each column per row as own value. if I say i,r,p = GUI.listbox.item(row_id)["value"] it takes all three columns in one row as one value, or ?

Comment: `i` is player name, `r` is the rating and `p` is the price.